# How to delay(backcount) in c?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Can anyone show me how to delay or back count in c ? I mean write 1 and 2 after a second. The only way I know is

```
include<windows.h>

Sleep( 1000 /* milliseconds */ );
```

can anyone please show me another way to do this? **(I have windows 8)**

Comment: C ___or___ C++. Make your choice. Not both.

Comment: Do not write multi-language source files. It is **very hard work** and often the result is neither one language or the other.

Comment: @pmg Can be quite reasonable for C/C++, actually. I do it all the time.

Comment: @user2129387, you've tagged with windows.  Do you want a Windows only solution, or solutions that will work in another OS?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin do you `#include <stdio.h>` or `#include <cstdio>` or what? ??? :)

Comment: I use only windows for now. And I used <stdio.h>.

Comment: Why do you want to change something that works?

Answer (score 2):

If you're limited to Standard C89

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    time_t t;

    /* wait until the Standard clock ticks */
    t = time(0);
    while (time(0) == t) /* void */;

    /* print 1 */
    puts("1");

    /* wait until the Standard clock ticks again */
    t = time(0);
    while (time(0) == t) /* void */;

    /* print 2 */
    puts("2");

    return 0;
}
```

If you can use POSIX: use [nanosleep()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html).

Comment: @pmg, since this is the only C answer, you might also suggest difftime().  For the OP, this is a blocking implementation, so if you want blocking behavior, then this will work on a multitasking OS like Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `thrd_sleep`, which is available in C11, and write a simple wrapper for it:

```
void sleep(time_t seconds){
    struct timespec ts, remaining;
    timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
    ts.tv_sec += seconds;
    while(thrd_sleep(&ts,&remaining) == -1){
        timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
        ts.tv_sec += remaining.tv_sec;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set an alarm using `alarm()` to be fired a second later then call `pause()`.

Comment: Just noticed the `winapi` tag: I'm unsure if there is  `alarm()` available in this environment.

Comment: The windows pendant to `alarm()` would be `SetTimer()`. Although just replacing it won't work. As there also seems to be no `pause()`under windows.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `select()` would be another, and also portable solution, although quite unconventional approach to (just) generate a delay.